# Get Subscription ID of a PayPal subscription with a trial period

Tags: python, django, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-subscriptions

I need to implement a system in which users will have a trial period in their subscription and after that period the user should resume their subscription, I have achieved the same but when a user needs to be deleted the subscription has to be terminated for that when i researched I got an API to cancel a subscription via

> https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/billing/subscriptions/I-BW452GLLEG1P/cancel

where **I-BW452GLLEG1P** in the above is the subscription id, but I don't get a subscription id when I create a subscription via the method suggested on the reference page

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/subscriptions/customize/trial-period/

please share your thoughts if you encountered similar issues
thanks

Comment: you are creating plan with free trial days, you are not creating subscription

Answer (score 0):

The page you reference is to create a plan. Plans are then used to create subscriptions.

To create a subscription using a plan, you can use an API call or a JS button.  The JS button is generally best since you need a buyer to approve the subscription anyway for it to be useful.

The documentation for creating a button is at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/subscriptions/integrate/#3-create-payment-button

Here is the relevant HTML/JS from there.

```
  <script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&vault=true&intent=subscription">
  </script> // Add your client_id

  <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

    <script>
      paypal.Buttons({
        createSubscription: function(data, actions) {
          return actions.subscription.create({
            'plan_id': 'YOUR_PLAN_ID' // Creates the subscription
          });
        },
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
          alert('You have successfully created subscription ' + data.subscriptionID); // Optional message given to subscriber
        }
      }).render('#paypal-button-container'); // Renders the PayPal button
    </script>
```

Comment: It is in the client-side onApprove function's `data`, so you can send it to your server from there and for robustness you can also subscribe to a webhook of type BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.ACTIVATED https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/event-names/#subscriptions .  To reconcile approved subscriptions with what they were for, you can set an arbitrary `custom_id` in the create JSON.